# How to add lines in the require section of composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to add "illuminate/html": "5.*" into the require section in composer.json file.

Comment: You trying to install illuminate html package ?

Comment: i already have an app and i want to add the following lines in the require section of composer.json file and run composer update "illuminate/html": "5.*".

Comment: Cool, let me tell you the better way rather than touching the `composer.json` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing the `composer.json` I would recommend you this cool way to install the `illuminate/html`

To navigate the project folder where it has `composer.json` and then do

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

Once it updates, in the `app.php`

Just add these two lines

Under Illuminate

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Under aliases

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

And then you can freely link the css like

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

And JS like

```
{!! HTML::script('js/script.js'); !!}
```

You shall refer my [post](http://sysaxiom.com/how-to-install-illuminatehtml-in-laravel-5/) for brief details

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but  i can see a lot of files that exisits in my project that has composer.json under the vendor directory.

Comment: Welcome, You might not look at the vendor folder. You can just open the command prompt. and do `cd..` to navigate to your project folder and run the command i given :)

Comment: after following the steps i got this error.
FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 210:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::style()

Comment: Have you added those lines in the `app.php` file ? If so, Have you inserted those lines in proper arrays ?

Comment: Yes. I did, i inserted the lines in proper arrays.

Comment: Well, i doubled checked there was something missing i fixed it, but it seems that i cannot load the css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82401/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-user3010296).